# Strange error with ldconfig

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-12.04

I get such an error when I run ldconfig

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't link /usr/lib//work/igloo/riff/loader_communication/build/liblcm.so.1 to liblcm.so.1
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Does the file exist? Do you have write permissions for the folder in question? have you tried running it a root?

Comment: @terdon the file does not exist. And i tried it as root

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you are trying to use ldconfig to explicitly link a file that does not exist of course it is failing.

Comment: @terdon I am not trying to edit it. ldconfig runs automatically after any apt-get installation. I haven't edited any file regarding ldconfig.